# Cloud Run Structuring an API Best Practice

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm designing an API for a large application that has many sub-functions and I am wondering what the best practice is for deploying it on Cloud Run and using it with the new API Gateway.

Example, say I have multiple modules that have multiple functions, I'll take a book store app as an example:

admin - Create User

admin - Delete User

admin - Get User Details

books - Create books

books - Get Books

books - Delete Books

user - Add to cart

user - Delete from cart

user - File new complaint

user - Checkout

In such a scenario, is it best practice to deploy each function as its own seperate Cloud Run deployment or should I deploy say 3 seperate Cloud Run deployments such as Admin, Books and User each with its respective functions. Or should I just deploy all of these in 1 large deployment with the specification of the endpoints in my flask app?

What are the benefits and drawbacks of those approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is opinion based, so Stack Overflow is not the right place to deliberate about this. (I personally voted to close, reason: "opinion based".)

Similarly this is not a Cloud Run (or even GCP) question and  your question can be generalized as "what are the benefits of running API endpoints as separate services".

The discussion around this can have tens of arguments, some of the first ones come to mind are:

- bad idea to separate if you need services to be revved altogether by deploying a single app
- good idea to separate if different endpoints have different teams, or different deployment cadences, or written in different languages
- bad idea to separate if they rely on a lot of cached state that's supposed to be within the same local memory
- good idea to separate if the endpoints have different scaling needs (e.g. /foo is called at 2 qps but /bar is 10k qps) so you can deploy them independently or consider rewriting/refactoring different endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

In the idea, you have 3 services: Admin, Book and User. Don't create a function per endpoint.

Now, your question depends on many things and I think your question will be closed. However, I can simply recommend you to search about the difference between monolith and microservices.

Microservices scale independently and allow a better release cycle (each team work on their part, and deliver independently). However, this architecture implies service to service communication (and monitoring -> Istio is popular for that!), latency, integration test complexity,...

If the benefits don't outweigh the issues, prefer a monolith architecture (i.e. only one Cloud Run services for the 3 services). Especially if it's the same team that develops all the services and if you don't need to scale independently.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasnt to clear in my question. These APIs are serving a frontend app. So a front end user is clicking on buttons to create books, or create users or an admin is trying to delete users things like that.

Thanks for your opinion, I am aware of monolith vs microservices. The reason why I am posting this question is to get a feel from the community about how different people go about organising their endpoints and deployments.

Comment: IMO: Functions is the Glue (link 2 services, with few/no processing, mainly API Calls, most of the time event driven). Container (Cloud Run, App Engine, K8S): microservice VS monolith consideration.